# Laravel Eloquent Rlationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an **`users`** table. It contain `role_id`. Admin can create users. Admin created  users will be store in **`users`** table where admin is also stored. Now I want to fetch admin created users. What should be the database design?

Comment: database design or relationships in models?

Comment: You mean like a column (like `created_by`) or how your relation should be in the model?

Comment: I don't want to add created_by column on users table. Is it possible to take separate table containing user_id and created_by column? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create user migration should be like

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('created_by')->unsignedInteger()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Now you can save as null or assign user id for created_by

```
$user = new User();
$user->created_by = Auth::id(); //if not logged in you can set null
$user->save();
```

you can fetch the users this way

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('created_by', Auth::id())->first(); // to get one record

$users = DB::table('users')->where('created_by', Auth::id())->get(); // to get all records
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `created_by_id` field to your `users` table via migration:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('created_by_id');
```

In your Users model add:

```
public function createdBy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Store the user:

```
public function store($request)
{
    $user = new User();
    // Other stuff
    $user->created_by_id = Auth::id();
    $user->save();
}
```

To use it:

```
$user = User::find(5);
$admin = $user->createdBy;
```

Comment: $user->created_by_id = Auth::id(); will not work when user will try to register itself. You cant set default value null bcz it's a unsigned.

Comment: You was asking about an admin creates a new user not a user registered itself. I don't provide you the full code. A little bit of work is on your side.

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you to add a enum type column name 'type', in which you should specify the type of user (for example admin, member) .
Then your query will be

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE type='admin'
```

Comment: Is it possible to create separate table and make relationship

Comment: which relationship do u want to make?

Answer (score -2):

You dont need to different table to fetch data.
Read some documentation regarding to sql and fetch from users tables.
so it should be like this:

```
'Select * from users';//this is the simple query to fetch all users from table name users.
```

Comment: can you please send me table structure?